# Android:how to iterate an ArrayList<String> in different thread

Tags: java, android

I need to iterate an ArrayList of String in a different thread, I don't need to add or delete items, just to iterate.

How can I do it?

Comment: ...The normal way to iterate over an `ArrayList`?  You just need to get a reference to the `ArrayList` to the other thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weill in its most basic form you do something like this.  But it seems like there's a lot more to your question than you asked us?

```
final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.addAll(stuff);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    for (Item item: items) {
      System.out.println(item);
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: how to refresh back the ArrayList in main thread if I change something in the second thread ?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue you may encounter with this, that the reading thread accesses the same data as the publisher thread. For that you need to pass the reference to the other thread in thread-safely manner (i.e. via a field declared with `volatile` modifier, using `AtomicReference` or pass the memory barrier in reader and writer threads by any other way, like passing a `ReentrantLock` or `synchronize` block). Note - that you do not need to iterate it *inside* a synchronization. Just pass the memory barrier before reading the list.

For example (ReentrantLock):

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

final Lock w = lock.writeLock();
w.lock();
try {
    // modifications of the list
} finally {
    w.unlock();
}

  .................................

final Lock r = lock.readLock();
r.lock();
try {
    // read-only operations on the list
    // e.g. copy it to an array
} finally {
    r.unlock();
}
// and iterate outside the lock
```

Comment: Good Eugene, could you please show some example how to sync between the main thread and the second thread a ArrayList of String?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            mylist.add("I");
            mylist.add("Am");
            mylist.add("definitely");
            mylist.add("becoming");
            mylist.add("a");
            mylist.add("better");
            mylist.add("programmer");
            Iterator<?> i1 = mylist.iterator();
            while (i1.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(i1.next());
            }
        }

    };
    splashThread.start();
}
```